# Grabbing values from API response

Tags: python

How would I grab values from this api response using python?

http://tinychat.com/api/find.room/randomroom

Comment: How about pasting a sample response into the question?

Answer (score 1):

It's basic XML data. You can parse it with an XML parser. I don't remember off the top of my head how to use the built-in XML parser, so here's how to do it with BeautifulSoup:

```
import requests
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup

data = requests.get('http://tinychat.com/api/find.room/randomroom').text
soup = BeautifulStoneSoup(data)

response = dict(soup.find('response').attrs)
geoip = dict(soup.find('geoip').attrs)
```

Now, `response` and `geoip` contain Python dictionaries, which you can easily work with:

```
{
    u'rt': u'5.47',
    u'roomtype': u'show',
    u'name': u'tinychat^randomroom',
    u'referer': u'',
    u'rtmp': u'rtmp://209.212.144.86:443/tinyconf',
    u'time': u'1354934566',
    u'result': u'RES'
}
```